# Subversion behind router

Tags: svn, configuration, proxy, router

Amidst my busy schedule at work, I occasionally find some time to study/code/work on my pet ASP.net projects (most of them exploring new concepts/designs). And  I do that @ home too, during weekends/evenings/free time. One major difficulty I found was that I am starting to maintain 2 code bases (one in office, one at home). Am behind a proxy @ work and behind a wireless router at home (the ISP gives me a dynamic IP I believe). And at both places, I have WinXP. Is there a way I can configure any source control (hopefully open source, and may be subversion, as I know to use it). I can access my machine at home from work  using TeamViewer, so can find my IP/change settings etc. Is there a way to configure subversion at my home computer so that  I can access it from work ?

Comment: The simplest solution would be to use local version control. You can put an SVN repo on a USB stick (it's just a folder). Or go all the way and use distributed version control, then you can even have multiple repos.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are unable to access your home Subversion instance because you have it set up to use the **svn://** protocol, which your work router is blocking..?

Instead, you could set up your home Subversion server to use **https://** protocol.  Your work router is more likely to permit **https://** traffic (port 443) than **svn://** traffic (port 3690).  HTTP over port 80 would also work, but I'd prefer SSL for protecting my source code.

Here's an article that discusses setting up a Subversion server on Windows with Apache (for http protocol: [How to Setup Subversion + Apache + WebSVN on Windows](http://turnleft.inetsolution.com/2007/07/how_to_setup_subversion_apache_1.html).  Here's another article: [HOWTO: Subversion for Windows with Apache server - a beginner's guide](http://svn.spears.at/)

To solve your dynamic IP issue, use a service like [DynDNS.com](http://www.dyndns.com).

Comment: Thanks for the links. My question is, will I have any issues accessing SVN server which is behind the router ?

Comment: If you're referring to your home router, you'll need to have it forward port 443 (https) to whichever box is your SVN server, once it's configured. I've got a web server at home running https on port 443 and it's behind a router as well.. I have had no problems.

Answer (score 1):

Phew, I found that google  (and MS codeplex) can host your code in SVN. I created a new project in google code and it solves my purpose. AnkhSVN & TortoiseSVN serve my purpose. The only thing is I have to agree to some sort of open source license and this repo is for my personal use, so not too concerned about the license

Answer (score 1):

I used google code with SVN, and then later switched to HG. Never had any problems until my employer started blocking https through the proxy.

Comment: HG?? what is that ?

Comment: HG is the chemical symbol for Mercury, and the acronym is used for http://mercurial.selenic.com/ another SCM system. Personally I've had Github recommended to me as a hosted source code solution, if you're willing to convert to git.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a different approach would be to use an external provider of svn hosting.
Then you have also access from everywhere and a backup.
I use http://www.projectlocker.com/ for my pet projects an I'm very happy.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to forward your Subversion server to the public internet via the port forwarding of you router.  This can usually be configured in the control interface of the router. Also, you'll need the external IP of your router; easiest way would be to use something like DynDNS.

Just make sure the server is always well patched. :-)

Another possibility would be to use a hosted SVN server somewhere. There are both free and paid options available.

Comment: Can you let me know where I can get free SVN hosting ?

Comment: If you are willing to have your software distributed as open-source, then some of the open source hosters will do (sourceforge.net, savannah.nongnu.org ). Otherwise, you could talk to your hosting company, maybe you can work something out. There are also some paid SVN hosting companies that offer free account for small projects; just google for them.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for off-topic, but are you aware that if your pet project will eventually grow into something useful, your employer can claim ownership of it (because you are using his time and resources)?

Comment: I doubt it. Am real busy at work with strict deadlines to meet. I sometimes work weekends too. My primary goal is to have a version control outside of my laptop as my laptop crashed multiple times recently and lost a lot of my work.

Answer (score 0):

Try [subversion Edge](http://www.collab.net/products/subversion). Also if you want to access your version controlling server remotely, then you need a public IP and the port to the subversion server should be forwarded. or you can use the free [Git repository](http://offers.assembla.com/free-git-hosting/)